# Navigate to another screen without the previous scaffold in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

My app has a main screen with a Scaffold and a BottomNavigation bar:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomBar(navController = navController)
                    }
                ) {
                    NavigationGraph(navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

...

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = BottomMenuOption.Home.route) {

        composable(route = BottomMenuOption.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = BottomMenuOption.Settings.settings) {
            SettingsScreen()
        }
        composable(route = BottomMenuOption.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }

       composable(route = "feature") {
           FeatureScreen()
       }
    }

}
```

`FeatureScreen` has it's own `Scaffold` with a `topBar` instead of a bottomBar and when I navigate to it from `HomeScreen`, I want to replace the previous one from the main screen and just see a topBar but instead, I'm seeing the two bars in the screen.

```
@Composable
fun FeatureScreen() {
    Scaffold (
        topBar = {
            TopBar(" Feature Screen")
        }
            )  {

    }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this? I'm thinking it could be done by just using a new Activity but ideally, I would like to keep the Single Activity approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new function like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainScaffold(
    topBar: @Composable (() -> Unit) = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable (() -> Unit) = {},
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit){
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = bottomBar,
        topBar = topBar,
        content = content
    )
}
```

then, use this main scaffold in your screens:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    MainScaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) },
        content = {
        // content
     })
}
```

and in your feature screen:

```
@Composable
fun FeatureScreen() {
    MainScaffold (
        topBar = {
            TopBar(" Feature Screen")
        }
    )  {
        //content
    }
}
```

and in setContent

```
setContent {
       val navController = rememberNavController()
       VoiceAssistantJetpackComposeTheme {
           NavigationGraph(navController = navController)
       }}
```

Comment: Yeah, this did the trick nicely. Thanks!

Comment: With this solution BottomBar is not shared between the screens, is that the desired behavior? Won't UI flick when switching between tabs since the bottom bar has to be drawn again and again?