# Jetpack Compose - Navigate both with and without BottomBar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnav

i have a Jetpack Compose project that includes navigating using a `Scaffold` with a `BottomBar`. By the way, in specific screens, i would like to being able to navigate outside of the `innerPadding` scope of the `Scaffold` and just have the composable to be displayed in full screen.

Using [official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) approach is fine only until you just need to navigate clicking on the items of the `BottomBar`.

I found a workaround solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560579/navigate-to-another-screen-without-the-previous-scaffold-in-jetpack-compose) where you use this:

```
@Composable
fun OneScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    MainScaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) },
        content = {
        // content
     })
}
```

for screens where `BottomBar` needs to be displayed and this:

```
@Composable
fun AnotherScreen() {
    MainScaffold ()  {
        //content
    }
}
```

for the screens where you don't need it to be diplayed.

I call this a "workaround solution" because in this way you need to regenerate the `BottomBar` on every screen, making it flashing everytime you click on one item because of recomposition (differently from standard BottomBar navigation).

I'm getting the feeling that there should be a more elegant solution, but i lack the experience to be sure of it and i have not been able to find it until now.

**EDIT**: **I was WRONG on a relevant aspect**. The flashing is not because of recomposition but because of the `Transition Animation` (Fade out/Fade in) provided by the `Navigation` component. Hence, it is possible to eliminate the 'flashing' issue setting No animation on transition. Of course this is still a work-around solution because it limit the user on the flexibility in animating the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that i believe to be better than the one linked in the previous post.
I decided to use the following approach:

- Use the `NavGraph` navigation for all the `Screens` that don't include `BottomBar`
- Use a conditional composable generation for the `BottomBar` Screen items

In this way i think it is easier to manage the `Transition Animations` and having readable code.
I'm sure **this is not the best solution** (and i'm not going to mark this as solution) but i think it's worth sharing the approach.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyBottomNavTestTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavGraph(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NavGraph

```
const val TEST_ROUTE = "test_route"

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.MainScreen.route,
        route = TEST_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(Screen.MainScreen.route) { MainScreen(navController) }
        composable(Screen.AnotherScreen.route) { AnotherScreen(navController) }
    }
}
```

MainScreen

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController){

    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0)}

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { MyBottomNavBar() {selectedItem = it} }
    ) {
            selectedItem ->
            when (selectedItem){
                0 -> TabOne(navController)
                1 -> TabTwo(navController)
                2 -> TabThree(navController)
            }

    }
}

@Composable
fun MyBottomNavBar(
    onSelectedItem: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    BottomNavigation() {
        BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = true,
            onClick = { onSelectedItem(0) },
            icon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Person, contentDescription = "Person Icon") },
            enabled = true,
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = true,
            onClick = { onSelectedItem(1) },
            icon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Phone, contentDescription = "Phone Icon") },
            enabled = true,
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = true,
            onClick = { onSelectedItem(2) },
            icon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Place, contentDescription = "Place Icon") },
            enabled = true,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabOne(navController: NavHostController){
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Text(
            text = "TabOne"
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabTwo(navController: NavHostController){
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Text(
            text = "TabTwo"
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabThree(navController: NavHostController){
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Column(){
            Text(
                text = "TabThree"
            )
            Button(onClick = {navController.navigate(Screen.AnotherScreen.route)}){
                Text("Go to AnotherScreen")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AnotherScreen

```
@Composable
fun AnotherScreen(navController: NavHostController){
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {navController.navigate(Screen.MainScreen.route)}) {
            Text("Go to MainScreen")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are not using navigation to navigate between your tab routes

Comment: Yes, that's exact, but I'm still using Navigation as a "top level navigation". I preferred to preserve the ability to have smooth or customizeable transitions more than managing the BottomBar generation and visibility everytime just to use only Navigation. Btw, as i already said, this is a workaround more than a solution. Still, it works. Any better solution Is more than welcomed

Comment: Thanks for this. Was fighting between using two NavHosts or hiding the Bottom Nav. So far this solution is working just fine in my application